# Indicator for current price in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

Is there a way to create an indicator which reflects the current price of a stock in Pine Script? I need this indicator because I need to enter an order before the candle closes (when there is a specific crossover) and the data for back testing is provided bar by bar. I think an indicator can allow me to do this and if not is there another way to tackle this.

I am not an experienced pine scripter and any help will be greatly appreciated:)
Thanks,

Comment: Yes, this would be super useful. I have a label at the last bar with the current open PnL and it needs to display the current close price for that. It's a strategy with 24h bars so there would be a 1d delay in PnL following...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `close` during the unconfirmed bar represents the current price of the asset.

However, Tradingview's backtesting engine will execute the order only on the next candle. See here why - https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#execution-model

Answer (score 8):

This answer is late, but since the solution is not posted, I will provide it here.
To solve this, you need pinescript to calculate the prices on the fly, and this is a feature you should turn on.
Check the following example:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="My Strategy", calc_on_every_tick=true)
```

`calc_on_every_tick` variable should be set to `true`, and there you go.
Now the `close` value represents the current price, and not bar-close.

Source: [Calculate bars on every tick](https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/calculate-every-tick/)